# How does the "Unicode Hex Input" input source work?

Tags: snow-leopard, input-source

How can I enter a character using that input source? I tried entering a tab character with <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, but I didn't get anything. Viceversa, with <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>, I get 香.

Am I doing anything wrong, or doesn't the input source allow to enter control codes?

I tested those codes on Firefox 4.

Comment: Make sure you're using the hex codes for the characters.

Comment: The ASCII code for the tab character is 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right by pressing <kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>.

My guess would be that Firefox, like many browsers, doesn't like tab characters (especially with forms). Try in TextEdit; it should work there.

Comment: Safari accepts the tab characters entered in that way, but Firefox and Opera seem to not like them.

Comment: Firefox seems to have built its own keyboard input system, as many of the standard OS X key controls don't work properly there, like control-O, control-V, control-Y, and control-T.  It's not surprising that Unicode Hex Input doesn't work, either.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

They are Unicode hex codes, see http://unicode.org/